# pySpark writerStream not showing output to console in Jupyter Lab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to display some streaming data (twitter feeds) to screen.
This is being done so I can follow better what is going on in Spark (debugging to a certain extent), but I am not getting any output.
Writing to csv file works ok for the same query but to console nothing is coming out.
I am using Jupyter Lab.
The query is;

```
    tweets_query = tweets\
    .selectExpr("cast(value as string)")\
    .select( f.from_json(f.col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("tweets"))\
    .select( "tweets.id", "tweets.text", "tweets.createdOnDate", "tweets.lang", "tweets.loc")
```

The part to write to the screen;

```
    query = tweets_query \
        .writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .option("truncate","false") \
        .start()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the await. add the following line after you start the query.

`sparkSession.streams.awaitAnyTermination()`